# Prometheus - Convert cpu_user_seconds to CPU Usage %?

Tags: performance, performance-testing, cpu-usage, prometheus

I'm monitoring docker containers via Prometheus.io. My problem is that I'm just getting `cpu_user_seconds_total` or `cpu_system_seconds_total`.

How to convert this ever-increasing value to a CPU percentage?

Currently I'm querying:

```
rate(container_cpu_user_seconds_total[30s])
```

But I don't think that it is quite correct (comparing to top).

How to convert `cpu_user_seconds_total` to CPU percentage? (Like in top)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Rate returns a per second value, so multiplying by 100 will give a percentage:

`rate(container_cpu_user_seconds_total[30s]) * 100`

Comment: From a blog post (also by @brian-brazil) I found a missing point: "these values always sum to one second per second for each cpu, [so] the per-second rates are also the ratios of usage."

Comment: Here you are using a value of `[30s]`. In your blog post (https://www.robustperception.io/understanding-machine-cpu-usage), you mention a value of `[1m]`. Some users are using quite larger values. What's the difference and how to find the correct value?
And what impact does `100 - (avg by (instance)` have?

Comment: For idiots like me. The rate function over a cpu seconds counter reads "How many seconds did the cpu work every second?". 1 second every second on 1 core will be 100%. 3 cores at 50% will be 1.5 seconds every second, etc... The bracket is the averaging window, longer periods will flatten the graph. Tune according to how erratic your cpu usage is.

Answer (score 51):

I also found this way to get CPU Usage to be accurate:

```
100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="node",mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100)
```

From: http://www.robustperception.io/understanding-machine-cpu-usage/

Comment: I don't know why, but I tested this on a local desktop with prometheus and a website running and it reported 99% CPU usage. Which is highly unlikely given how the system reports 10% CPU usage.

Comment: This for 0.16 and above version of node exporter for 0.15 and below version you can use ```100 * (1 - avg by(instance)(irate(node_cpu{job='node',mode='idle'}[5m])))```

Comment: Does it sum all CPU cores? Why does Node Exporter Full Grafana dashboard use this instead? (((count(count(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance=~"$node:$port",job=~"$job"}) by (cpu))) - avg(sum by (mode)(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode='idle',instance=~"$node:$port",job=~"$job"}[5m])))) * 100) / count(count(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance=~"$node:$port",job=~"$job"}) by (cpu))

Comment: I would prefer using `rate()` instead of `irate()`, since `irate()` can be quite noisy - https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832

Answer (score 17):

Note that `container_cpu_user_seconds_total` and `container_cpu_system_seconds_total` are per-container counters, which show CPU time used by a particular container in `user space` and in `kernel space` accordingly (see [these docs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87625/what-is-difference-between-user-space-and-kernel-space) for more details). [Cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/) exposes additional metric - `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total`. This metric equals to the sum of the `container_cpu_user_seconds_total` and `container_cpu_system_seconds_total`, e.g. it shows overall CPU time used by each container. See [these docs](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/85796f19bf1986040f2b9644857fd46811b737f6/docs/storage/prometheus.md) for more details.

The `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` is a [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter), e.g. it increases over time. This isn't very informative for determining CPU usage at a particular time. Prometheus provides [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) function, which returns the average per-second increase rate over counters. For example, the followign query returns the average per-second increase of per-container `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` metrics over the last 5 minutes (see `5m` lookbehind window in square brackets):

```
rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m])
```

This is basically the average number of CPU cores used during the last 5 minutes. Just multiply it by 100 in order to get CPU usage in %. Note that the resulting value may exceed 100% if the container uses more than a single CPU core during the last 5 minutes.

The `rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m])` usually returns a TON of time series with many long labels in production Kubernetes, so it is better to use the following queries:

#### The average number of CPU cores used during the last 5 minutes per each pod:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!=""}[5m])) by (pod)
```

#### The average number of CPU cores used during the last 5 minutes per each node:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!=""}[5m])) by (node)
```

#### The average number of CPU cores used during the last 5 minutes per each namespace:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!=""}[5m])) by (namespace)
```

The `container!=""` filter removes superfluous metrics related to `cgroups` hierarchy - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281327/why-container-memory-usage-is-doubled-in-cadvisor-metrics/69282328#69282328) for more details.

Comment: Why do you include `container!=""`?

Comment: Please see the last sentence in the answer

Answer (score 4):

For Windows Users - wmi_exporter

```
100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(wmi_cpu_time_total{mode="idle"}[2m])) * 100)
```