# Prometheus cpu seconds to percentage

Tags: alert, monitoring, prometheus

I would like to set an alert in prometheus when the usage of cpu is > 85%.

My host exposes this metrics.

```
process_cpu_seconds_total[5m])
```

How can I convert it into percentage cpu usage?

Comment: That looks like a system metric, not a Kafka JVM one

Comment: Yes, this is host level broker metrics exposed by kafka .

Comment: Sure. My point is that this seems unrelated to Kafka, rather just Prometheus or more specifically AlertManager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prometheus - Convert cpu\_user\_seconds to CPU Usage %?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923788/prometheus-convert-cpu-user-seconds-to-cpu-usage)

Answer (score 3):

```
irate(process_cpu_seconds_total{job="prometheus"}[5m]) * 100 / 2 (number of CPU cores)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
irate(process_cpu_seconds_total{job="prometheus"}[5m])*10
```